# Accessibility: 2 links with same text and different HREF

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, screen-readers

In a web application I have lists of things with the following structure:

[image: list of roles]

As you can see, when we list items (users, roles or anything basically), we have some associated actions on the right, highlighted on yellow.  In this case all items have a `Delete` option.

However, if I run a ADA compliance tool, I get a warning saying:

> Warn: Ensure that links that point to different HREFs use different
>   link text.

What would be correct way to fix this as all the `Delete` links obviously point to a different link (for example: `javascript:Delete(123)`). I know it's just a warning I could ignore, but it might be good to fix it.

I don't want to change the link text to `Delete XYZ` as it would be way redundant and it might not fit in the screen either.

I'm using the Firefox's [Accessibility Evaluation Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/accessibility-evaluation-toolb/) for the test.

Edit: When using a screen reader, the tab order is `Administrator`, `Delete`, `Advisor`, `Delete`, `Instructor`, `Delete`, ... as the items are also links that take you to the details/edit of each of those items. I'm not an expert on accessibility, but it looks redundant since it's already reading the item before each `Delete`.

Comment: I think I would change them to `Delete Adminstrator`, `Delete Advisor`, etc. Yes, that's somewhat redundant and longer, but only if you can see what `Delete` is next to, if you couldn't see the screen and a screen reader just read "Delete Delete Delete..." would you know which button to choose? And even for sighted users, the delete button is a ways from the title, so it doesn't hurt as a reminder of what `Delete` will actually be deleting. And +1 for actually doing accessibility testing!

Comment: Thanks @blm. I forgot to say that when using a screen reader, the tab order is Administrator, Delete, Advisor, Delete, Instructor, Delete, ... as the items are also links that take you to the details/edit of each of those items. I'm not an expert on accessibility, but it looks redundant.

Comment: Ok, that would be clearer then. I do like @staypuftman's suggestion below as well though.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on tab order to hear 'admin' before 'delete' because you can tab backwards too.  I'd hear 'admin', 'delete', 'advisor'.  Now I'm not sure which item delete pertains to.  Tabbing backwards I'd hear 'advisor' then 'delete' but that doesn't help me.  You should be able to put an aria-label on your delete tag and and have it say 'delete admin' or 'delete advisor', etc, like others have suggested.

Comment: @slugolicious good points. The aria-label doesn't work though, if not other solution comes up, the one suggested by staypuftman below seems to be correct solution. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a screenreader only class on a more descriptive element if you don't want to put the proper text labels in.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-screen-readers) has a really handy little style `.sr-only` you can add to your stylesheet for elements you only want screenreaders to see:

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
```

Just put the style on a more verbose version of the 'delete' div/span:

```
<div class="sr-only">Delete Administrator</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to staypuftman's suggestion, I would also use Bootstrap's .sr-only class but I would assign it to a span surrounding the extra words only so that you only see "Delete" in the button while the accessibly hidden text is part of the button semantically and will be read when the button has focus.

Like so:

```
<button type="button" id="deleteAdvisor">
    Delete
    <span class="sr-only"> Advisor</span>
</button>
```